# ReactJS SPA project back / forward buttons on browser won't save the user path

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, single-page-application

I'm having a problem while trying to develop a SPA project with ReactJS, which back/forward buttons on browser won't work, like if the path of the user is not saving, something that's not happening with another project of a friend of mine ( he's developing a SPA too ).
I will show some demos below and the way I'm redirecting the user.

Redirect method

```js
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate()
    const redirect = (url)=>{
        navigate(url, {replace:true})
    }
<Navbar.Brand onClick={()=>{redirect('/')}}>eCommerce</Navbar.Brand>
```

Video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1klkTUxOtgr0oJIOAMRCOnoPKu0Ac7x9e/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using `navigate(url)` in place of `navigate(url, {replace:true})`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of useNavigate(), you can utilise useHistory() hook to achieve this. Replace your code something like below:

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";

const history = useHistory();
<Navbar.Brand onClick={()=>{history.push('/')}}>eCommerce</Navbar.Brand>
```